# Pass data from Parse tableview to WatchKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, watchkit

I'm using **`Parse` to create this table view**, and am trying to figure out **how to get the table data, so I can pass it into the WatchKit** `InterfaceController`.

(Would I need to query `Parse` to somehow get and store the data in an `array` which I would then be able to call from the WatchKit `InterfaceController` `awakeWithContext`?)

*Here is what I have, let me know if I can add anything that would be helpful:*

`TableVC.m`:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        self.parseClassName = @"na";
        self.textKey = @"dateTime";
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    return query;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    UILabel *homeLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    homeLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"test"];

    UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
    dateLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"dateTime"];

    return cell;
}
```

`Parse` data:
[image]

`TableVC`:
[image]

I do have the the basic `WKInterfaceTable` set up, and all I need to do is have it show the same exact data as the `TableVC.m`.

So where I'm stuck is that I know I need an array of some sort in the `WKInterfaceTable` to use, but in my `TableVC.m` where I use `Parse` I'm not able to figure out how/what to do to get that to happen. And it seems like I would probably do a parse query in my viewDidLoad to pull the same corresponding `test` and `dateTime` for use in the `WKInterfaceTable`, but I'm not sure?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a good solution to this?

Comment: @user717452 nope, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you WatchKit extension you need to set up your table differently.  On iOS the UITableView queries your datasource as needed for cells.  On WatchKit you need to pass all of the data for a table at one time to you `WKInterfaceTable`.  I am not going to go into detail here for how to set up you table as you can find some great info here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Tables.html.

Also, I would suggest that you do your parse query in the background and then update your table after the data has returned.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I do have the the basic `WKInterfaceTable` set up.  So where I'm stuck is that I know I need an array of some sort in the `WKInterfaceTable` to use, but in my `TableVC.m` where I use `Parse` I'm not able to figure out how/what to do to get that.  And it seems like you are saying to probably do a parse query in my `viewDidLoad` to pull `test` and `dateTime` for use in the `WKInterfaceTable`?  I basically just want the same exact data in my `WKInterfaceTable`.

Comment: You will need to call `findObjects` on you `PFQuery` object to get your array.  Then you will need to set the number of rows on your WKInterfaceTable with `[table setNumberOfRows:results.count withRowType:@"MyRowTypeClass"];`  Then you will need to iterate over each result in the results returned from findObjects and call `MyRowTypeClass* row = [table rowControllerAtIndex:index];`.  You can then set the values form a result from your parse query on row. You will need to set up MyRowTypeClass as your own class with IBOutlets and use the storyboard for layout.

Comment: I've got the MyRowTypeClass and IBOutlets and Storyboard setup, so good to know I'm tracking with that.  Am I doing the PFQuery and such in the 'TableVC.m'?  Or am I able to do that in the `WKInterfaceTable`?  Because if its in the `TableVC.m` then I'm going to need to save that as a public `array` so my `WKInterfaceTable` can use it right, or am I thinking incorrectly about that?

Comment: I am not 100% sure I understand your code structure, but from what I understand you will want to have an outlet in your TableVC.m to your WKInterfaceTable and do the query in your TableVC.  Then set the data on the outlet for the WKInterfaceTable.